# Search on page script

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, uisearchbar

I've been trying to have a working search bar that searches text on the page. What I'm trying to accomplish is exactly what Ctrl+F does but in an input field for the user on the page. I have this so far which works great on desktop versions but will not work on mobile browsers:

```
<form id="f1" name="f1" action="javascript:void()" onsubmit="if(this.t1.value!=null &amp;&amp; this.t1.value!='')
parent.findString(this.t1.value);return false;">
<input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" value="" placeholder="Type here.." size="20">
<input type="submit" name="b1" value="Search">
</form>

<script>
    var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {
 if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
 var strFound;
 if (window.find) {

  // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

  strFound=self.find(str);
  if (!strFound) {
   strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
   while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
  if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
  alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
  return;
 }
 if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
 return;
}
</script>
```

I found this code [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm) which seems very old. It works but not on any mobile browser. So I'd appreciate any suggestions of an efficient way of achieving this. Thanks!

Comment: ctr-f is one of the most useful keyboard shortcut keys for me on stack.  looking forward to this question developing into something very useful for many.

Answer (score 0):

After searching, I found [this script](https://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/find6.htm) by Jeff Baker that functions exactly as I needed it to. Posting it here in case someone else is looking for something similar!

Comment: Funny that few lines of javascript requires a donation to get the download button. Digital beggers are in software industry now.